# How to set Android action bar menu item background dynamically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a use case where I need to create menu items and sub menus dynamically in onPrepareOptionsMenu and set those item's and sub menu's background colors dynamically.

The background colors are determined at runtime.  There isn't a pre-existing list of background colors I can put in XML (you can basically consider them to be RGB values typed into a text view in the same activity as the menu).

I only want to change the menu item's backgrounds if they are shown in popups (i.e. SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER or SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM when there is not enough room), not when they are shown directly in the action bar.

I know I can use a custom view inflater to change the background as the menu item views are inflated, but that requires reflection and depends on the View subclass's name.  That name might be different on different versions of Android or for different manufacturer's devices.

Is there a way to do this without depending on anything OS version- and device-specific?